# What is the name of the racing game in "The Rocker" (2008 film)?

Tags: game-identification

I’m looking for the name of the racing game in *[The Rocker](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1031969/reference/)*, a 2008 comedy film starring Rainn Wilson as "Fish". In one scene, Fish walks in on his nephew Matt and his friend Curtis playing a two-player split-screen racing game. Matt says it's an Xbox game, correcting Fish when he said “Playbox”.

You can see the clip and some screenshots of the game here:

[image: GIF of the game]

[image: screenshot][image: screenshot][image: screenshot]

Can anyone identify this game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like ***Project Gotham Racing 3*** based off of this video (around the 9 minute mark):

The UI looks identical:

[image]